# How to parse string in powershell

Tags: string, powershell, parsing

I have a Powershell command that outputs multiple lines.

I want to output only one line that contains the name of a .zip file.

Currently, *all* lines are returned when substring `.zip` is found:

```
$p.Start() | Out-Null
$p.WaitForExit()
$output = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
$output += $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
foreach($line in $output)
{  
  if($line.Contains(".zip"))
  {
     $line
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `.ReadToEnd()`, `$output` receives a *single, multi-line string*, not an array of lines.

You must therefore split that string into individual lines yourself, using the `-split` operator.
You can then apply a string-comparison operator such as `-match` or `-like` directly to the array of lines to extract matching lines:

```
# Sample multi-line string.
$output = @'
line 1
foo.zip
another line
'@

$output -split '\r?\n' -match '\.zip'  # -> 'foo.zip'
```

- `-split` is regex-based, and regex `\r?\n` matches newlines (line breaks) of either variety (CRLF, as typical on Windows, as well as LF, as typical on Unix-like platforms).
- `-match` is also regex-based, which is why the `.` in `\.zip` is `\`-escaped, given that `.` is a regex metacharacter (it matches any character other than LF by default).

  - Note that `-match`, like PowerShell in general, is case-*insensitive* by default, so both `foo.zip` and `foo.ZIP` would match, for instance;
    if you do want case-sensitivity, use `-cmatch`.

---

As an aside:

I wonder why you're running your command via a `[System.Diagnostics.Process]` instance, given that you seem to be invoking synchronously while capturing its standard streams.

PowerShell allows you to do that much more simply by direct invocation, optionally with redirection:

```
$output = ... 2>&1
```